# Mongodb Multiple and statement using PHP code

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I want a query like the following from mongodb using PHP code:

```
select * from orders where mrn=1234 and status!=cancelled and status!=delivered and status!=draft
```

I have tried the following code which is not working:

```
$filterpatient = array("order.patientinfo.mrn" => $reqresult, '$and' => array( 
    array('order.orderitem.status' => array('$ne' => array('cancelled','delivered')))
    ));
$cursor = $collection->find($filterpatient)->sort(array('_id'=>-1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try:
$collection->find(array("order.patientinfo.mrn" => $reqresult, 'order.orderitem.status' => array('$nin' => array("cancelled","delivered","draft"))))->sort(array('_id'=>-1));
```

**Mongodb query:**

```
db.orders.find({"mrn":1234,"status":{"$nin":["cancelled","delivered","draft"]}});
```

For more detail [Click here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is incorrect, firstly your mrn query should also be in the $and clause, and you should be using `$nin` (not in array) for your status. Your status query was also surrounded by two `array(` clauses.

```
$filterpatient = array('$and' => array(
    "order.patientinfo.mrn" => $reqresult, 
    "order.orderitem.status" => array('$nin' => array('cancelled','delivered', 'draft'))
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MongoDB_DataObject](https://github.com/viettranme/MongoDB_DataObject/) as below:

```
$model = new MongoDB_DataObject();

$model->query("select * from orders where mrn=1234 and status!='cancelled' and status!='delivered' and status!='draft'");

while ($model->fetch()) {
    var_dump($model);
}
```

OR:

```
$model = new MongoDB_DataObject('orders');

$model->whereAdd("mrn=1234 and status!='cancelled' and status!='delivered' and status!='draft'");

$model->find();

while ($model->fetch()) {
    var_dump($model);
}
```